# Twitter Bootstrap 2 fluid layout should fit screen (+ scrollable area)

Tags: css, layout, twitter-bootstrap, overflow

I try to implement a new Bootstrap-based Design.

[image]

How can I fit a fluid layout to the screen and create only one scrollable area (Content) ?

I tried to set body,html and all parent-tags of the Content-div to height:100%, overflow:hidden and only the Content is set to overflow:auto - but this doesn't work.

Any ideas?

The design consists of a fluid-layout and three rows (header:span2+span10, body:span2+span10, footer:span12)

EDIT: At the moment I use jQuery and resize it everytime the window-size changes - it works, but isn't a good solution..

Comment: give overflow:scroll to container div

Comment: Similar question, jquery solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048967/twitter-bootstrap2-100-height-responsive

Comment: Did the solution proposed by Vino work for you? (Doesn't for me).
If not, what did?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have something similar to this:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3">
        Sidebar
    </div>
    <div class="span9" style="overflow:auto">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

You can either set the CSS `height` (or even `max-height`) of *both* the sidebar div and the content div, or you can use something like [The EqualHeighs jQuery Plugin](http://www.cssnewbie.com/equalheights-jquery-plugin/) to dynamically set the heights the same (*remembering to set the minimum and maximum height:* `$(".x").equalHeights(100,300);`).