# How does bleeding works in CSS?

Tags: css

I recently read about the "holy grail" design and read implementations for it.

I saw a solution that does something strange on the menus from the sides.

```
{ 

    margin-bottom: -3200px;
    padding-bottom: 32000px;
}
```

I understand this mechanism causes the menu to be "infinite", I also found out this trick is called bleeding.

I don't understand how it works. Can someone please explain?

EDIT:

both answers were great. Wish I could pick 2. Picked the first one answered. I found another resource that emphasizes on negative margin values which explains bleed as well. 
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Padding-bottom at that value with stretch the background of the menu down far enough that it will always be seen to take up the whole length of the page. The margin adjustment gives the ability to still position content over this stretched out menu at a position according to the design of your site. Here is an example with the properties adjusted so that you can more easily see what is happening:

http://jsfiddle.net/PVKbp/23/

```
 .two
    {

   margin-bottom: -3200px;
    padding-bottom: 32000px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    background-color: #aaaaaa;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Bleed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleed_%28printing%29) in printing is where you create a design purposely extended over the boundaries of the canvas, to ensure that all the page is covered. It basically means that you won't get any dodgy white edges where your design didn't "fit" the document properly:

http://www.duggal.com/connect/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/bleed2.jpg

I suppose the idea of bleed is the same in this instance, whereby you're trying to cover having any potential white spaces by adding padding to the menu

**CSS**

The only "holy grail" I've heard of in CSS is the 3-column one? If this is the case, I would say that having padding 32000px will be needlessly resource intensive

I've never really created 100% height responsive stuff, so here's a good resource for you: [Twitter Bootstrap2 100% height responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048967/twitter-bootstrap2-100-height-responsive)

Comment: Okay, so you're trying to create a 3 column layout where all the columns are the same height? I suppose you want it to be demi-responsive, in that those columns adapt to the height of the viewport?